# Python - v3.6.3: Find a value in a list that meets a condition and then find another value that meets a different condition based on original value

Tags: python

I have a large list which contains co ordinates values with text. The format of an element in the list is as so which displays the index of the element, the x co ord, the y co ord and the text value.

- e.g. (245, (85, 604, '1 Text _'))

I want the number elements in the list to line up with its specific value of text.for e.g.

(1, (85, 604, '1 _'))

(2, (85, 604, '2 _'))

(3, (102, 604, '1s Text'))

(4, (102, 445, '2s Text'))

The resulting list should be like:

('1 _'1s Text')

('2 _'2s Text)

I search the original list for elements that are in the range of 84-86 at the start and which have a specific regex format which extracts all the elements that have a number at the start of the line and an '_'.

This is how I iterate through the list:

```
for i in enumerate(row):
    regex = r"(^\d+\s\_)"
    if i[1][0] in range(84,86) and i[1][1] in range(44, 230):
    if re.match(regex, i[1][2], re.MULTILINE):
        //So for the elements that meet this condition above^
          I then want to find the next value that has the range(101,103)
          //I have tried the following but I know this is not the right way to do it
          next(i[1][2] for l in i if i[1][0] in range(101,103)
```

If an element satisfies this condition, I then want to search for the closest element whose value of i[1][0] is in the range of 101 - 103.

for e.g.

(1, (85, 604, '1 _'))

(2, (85, 604, '2 _'))

(3, (102, 604, 'Text'))

(4, (102, 445, 'Text'))

So for the original condition this will obtain the value of index 1(85, 604, '1 _') and then I want my code to then obtain the value of index 3(102, 604, '3 _') as it is the next value of 102 and index 2 should line up with index 4.

My current code lines up index 2 with index 3 which is not what I want.

Can someone please help me to iterate through this list so once the original condition is found it will then find the next 102 element and so the text aligns with the correct number.

Comment: The result you want in the first step is not clear : one line contains 3 quotes, the second only 2 quotes, and both are not valid Python expressions. Where are the strings delimiters exactly ? Another question is the string "1st Text" in your result, the same as the string "1st Text" in item 3 from your first list ? How do you combine element 1 and 3 from your first list to get the result you wrote ?

Comment: Do you have exactly the same nb of values in range(84,86) as there are in range(102,105) ? And when you say "closest to" does it means closest in term of coordinates distance, or in term of list index ?

Comment: First, what have you tried? It sounds like you think you know how to do all of part one, but not all of part two? So give us the code, with a comment in the gap you don't know how to write, and just explain what you want that part to do and why you're stuck there, and we can answer a lot more easily.

Comment: Meanwhile, is there a reason this has to be a list of tuples? Could you preprocess it into, say, a sorted list of just the first half and a dict of the second half, in advance, so each lookup becomes trivial (and fast)? I understand you may not know how to do that preprocessing, but would it be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Don't put code in comments; edit your question.

Comment: As a side note: instead of `for i in enumerate(row):` and then using `i[0]` and `i[1]`, you can do `for i, col in enumerate(row)` and then use `i` and `col`. Or, since you don't seem to even be using the index in the first place, just `for col in row:`.

Comment: OK, cool. So what do you mean by "closest element that matches"? Closest index in the list? Closest euclidean distance?

Comment: I mean the closest index value that contains 102, sorry about not being clear

Comment: OK, is my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: Don't change your question into a completely new question just because you have a new problem. That makes the question useless to anyone who had your original problem, and the answer irrelevant. If your followup is too drastic to handle any other way, it's a new question, so create a new question.

Comment: Also, it would help if you write a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That includes input that can be copied and pasted as source, instead of just what it looks like when you loop over it and print it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again @abarnert I will know for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

This problem would be a lot easier to solve—and run a lot faster—if you transformed the data structure into something designed for searching, so you didn't have to keep walking the whole list over and over. But, sticking with what you have:

To find the first value after the found row that matches a new condition, we can just walk the list starting after the found row.

```
for i in enumerate(row):
    regex = r"(^\d+\s\_)"
    if i[1][0] in range(84,86) and i[1][1] in range(44, 230):
    if re.match(regex, i[1][2], re.MULTILINE):
        for j in enumerate(row[i[0]+1:], i[0]+1):
            if j[1][0] in range(101, 103):
                # do stuff with j
                break
        else:
            # handle the case where there was no match
```

---

By the way, the way you're looping is very weird. The `enumerate` function is designed to be used like this:

```
for index, value in enumerate(row):
```

And then you don't need to use `i[0]` and `i[1]` all over the place, just `index` and `value`.

Or, if you don't need the `index` (the `i[0]`) at all, just don't use `enumerate`:

```
for value in row:
```

Meanwhile, in your case, you probably want to unpack the values, not just the index and value

So, a more readable way of writing this would be:

```
regex = r"(^\d+\s\_)"
for i, (x, y, text) in in enumerate(row):
    if x in range(84,86) and y in range(44, 230):
    if re.match(regex, text, re.MULTILINE):
        for j, (x2, y2, text2) in enumerate(row[index+1:], index+1):
            if x2 in range(101, 103):
                # do stuff with x2, y2, text2
                break
        else:
            # handle the case where there was no match
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I just meant the next index value that contained the 102 value would be outputted. So if index 1 had 85, index 2 had 85, index 3 had 102. Index 3 would be the element that had the next value of 102 and then i just want to join the values of index 1 and 3.

Comment: @Sarahmc You mean the _first_ one, starting from `i[0]` and moving forward only? If so, see the edited answer. Also, please try to edit the question to make it clear what you want.

Comment: That code helps alot but is there anyway to do it so that once an 85 and its next 102 is found they can be added to a temp array and removed from original array? So for e.g. index 2 would not line up with index 3 in my question? @abarnert

Comment: @Sarahmc Sure. After you find your `i` and `j` successfully and do whatever you wanted with them, you can just `temparray.append((i, j))` then `del row[j[0]]` then `del row[i[0]]`. (Make sure you remove the later one first.) Or, if you reorganized your code with `for i, (x, y, text) etc.`, append the values to `temparray` in whatever format you want, then `del row[j]` then `del row[i]`.